# Method for evaluating limits at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

In my stewarts could book there is a theorem for limits to infinity that states if  r>0 is a rational number then $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{x^r}=0$.
My question is why does r have to be a rational number for example pi is greater than 0 and obeys this statement?

Comment: My guess is that exponentiation has not been defined for irrational numbers yet (i.e, only roots and integer exponents can be used.)

Comment: That's nonsense.

Comment: We may need to see it in context to say. Without that, multiple explanations occur, such as "we're talking about rational $r$ at the moment anyway", "we'll prove the rational case because it implies the real one", or "this is one of those sources that prefers to postpone definitions of irrational exponents until we can write $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$".

Comment: His proof for this needs $r$ rational (based on limit laws for exponents of the form $n$ and $1/n$, $n$ an integer). Of course your observation is correct.